# function for creating a summary table from sales data

Tags: r, kable, kableextra

I am looming for function to create a summary table where I can pass the table as input parameter and create a a summary like below, i am trying to create with dcast but does't able to make it dynamic for variables.

**Sample data frame**

```
target <- c("DT 0", "DT 1", "DT 2", "DT 3", "DT 4", "DT 5", "DT 6", "DT 7", "DT 8")
basic <- c(19,50,79,80,72,30,13,45,52)
beginner <- c(22,82,50,15,51,54,40,17,31)
medium <- c(18,66,29,32,40,34,57,60,84)
projected <- c(38,63,17,64,81,41,14,63,79)
Planned <- c(53,12,73,34,16,77,12,60,88)
df <- data.frame(target,basic,beginner,medium,projected,Planned)
df <- as.data.frame(t(df))
```

the required output should be like below

[image]

Comment: I am not sure I quite understood your desired summary table. You only need `basic` and `planned` columns?

Comment: yes only basic and plannes column rows , column would be Dt 0, DT 5. DT 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the best I could come up with, However I couldn't so far erase the `DT_` part from the second header since the names should be unique and it throws and error. I will try to figure it out soon.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(kableExtra)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(- target, names_to = "summary", values_to = "Banking") %>%
  filter(summary %in% c("basic", "Planned"),
         target %in% c("DT 0", "DT 5", "DT 8")) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = c("target", "summary"), values_from = Banking) %>%
  mutate(`Sales Review` = "Banking") %>%
  relocate(`Sales Review`) %>%
  kbl() %>%
  kable_classic() %>%
  add_header_above(c(" "= 1, "DT 0" = 2, "DT 5" = 2, "DT 8" = 2))
```

Here is the output [image: table].

Comment: Thanks for helping , this is the same answeri was loooking for but the only thing i wast to update the names DT 0_basic,DT 5_basic to only Basic and DT 0_Planned,DT 5_Planned to only planned

Comment: I know, I am thinking about it but I just can't remove it because column names cannot be duplicated values. Let me see what I can do.

Comment: I can replace it with almost anything, but there has to be something and it doesn't accept duplicate values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  select(target, basic, Planned) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = target, values_from = c(basic, Planned), 
              names_glue = '{target}_{.value}') %>%
  select(order(stringr::str_extract(names(.), 'DT \\d+')))
```

If you are using the transposed version of your data, use the following code.

```
df %>%
  rownames_to_column('val') %>%
  filter(val %in% c('target', 'basic', 'Planned')) %>%
  t %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  setNames(.[1, ]) %>%
  slice(-1) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = target, values_from = c(basic, Planned), 
              names_glue = '{target}_{.value}') %>%
  select(order(stringr::str_extract(names(.), 'DT \\d+')))
```

R dataframes can't have multiple headings, if you want the output to look exactly as shown you might look into functions like `knitr::kable` or `gt::gt` and other functions to display pretty tables.

Comment: actual data is transformed version of original df

Comment: my dear friend @Ronak Shah do you have any idea how I can get rid of those `DT \\d+` in the second row. Whenever I attempt to erase them an error is thrown due to the duplication in column names.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR Yes, you cannot have duplicate column names in a tibble.

Comment: @user14176250 That is unusual format to have. You can have a look at my updated answer which works for the transposed version of the data. Unfortunately, I don't have a solution with `melt`.

Comment: @RonakShah So there is nothing I can do to fix this.

Comment: I think with `kable` it should be possible but I am not much familiar with it.

Comment: I think package `kableExtra` is doing the same but the only problem in my code is that extra prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

#HackerRank Solution

```
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble::tribble(
~Region, ~Representative, ~Item, ~Units, ~Price, ~Total_sales,
"West","Paul","Juicer",19,80,1520,
"Central","Peter","Ceiling fan",2,100,200,
"West","Connor","Juicer",17,80,1360,
"Central","David","Ceiling fan",8,100,800,
"Central","Thomas","Dish washer",12,300,3600,
"East","Richard","Juicer",20,80,1600,
"East","John","Toaster",5,50,250,
"East","Jared","Ceiling fan",16,100,1600,
"East","Adam","Washing machine",6,600,3600,
"Central","Mark","Ceiling fan",7,100,700,
"Central","Jimmy","Washing machine",13,600,7800,
"East","Stuart","Washing machine",15,600,9000,
"West","Aishley","Dish washer",10,300,3000,
"East","Rafel","Toaster",18,50,900,
"East","Rafel","Juicer",18,50,900,
"Central","Jaminee","Washing machine",4,600,2400
)
totals <- df %>% 
group_by(Region, Representative) %>% 
summarize(total_sale = sum(as.numeric(Total_sales))) %>% 
arrange(desc(total_sale)) %>% 
slice_head(n = 1)
```